# Unity with the same interface, multiple factories

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container

So the issue, is when I declare:

```
[Dependency]
public AuthenticationService _authenticationServices { get; set; }
```

The `_authenticationServices` will constantly remain `null`.  It isn't referenced, which will throw a Null Reference Exception.  I'm assuming the issue stems from my Unity Configuration file:

```
container.RegisterType<ICrudFactory, ZNodeDataContextFactory>();
container.RegisterType<ICrudFactory, MincronDataContextFactory>();
```

Since they both use the same interface, but a separate concrete implementation.  The implementation is as follows:

```
public interface ICrud : IDisposable
{
     // Method's to be exposed, via general repository.
}

public interface ICrudFactory
{
     ICrud Create();
}

public ZNodeDataContext : DbContext, ICrud
{
     // Concrete implementation.
}

public MincronDataContext : DbContext, ICrud
{
     // Concrete implementation.
}

public ZNodeDataContextFactory : ICrudFactory
{
     ICrud ICrudFactory.Create()
     {
           return ZNodeDataContext();
     }
}

public MincronDataContextFactory : ICrudFactory
{
     ICrud ICrudFactory.Create()
     {
           return MincronDataContext();
     }
}

public class AuthenticationService
{
     private readonly ICrudFactory _factory;
     public AuthenticationService(ICrudFactory factory)
     {
         _factory = factory;
     }

     public void Sample()
     {
          using(var context = _factory.Create())
              context.Method(...);
     }
}
```

I'd like to keep that structure, to avoid code duplication.

Comment: How is `AuthenticationService` related to the factories?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Edited to include authentication service.

Comment: Which implementation of `ICrudFactory` do you want to inject to `AuthenticationService`?

Comment: Well, I'd like to do ZNodeDataContext but if I need the other, access it.

Comment: Add a default registration for it like this: `container.RegisterType<ICrudFactory, ZNodeDataContextFactory>();`

Comment: @YacoubMassad That is what I did.

Comment: Don't create a default registration for the other one. Keep the other one named.

Comment: By the way, is there a particular reason why are you using property injection and not constructor injection? Also, is there a reason why you use attributes (the `Dependency` attribute)?

Comment: @YacoubMassad The documentation mentioned it, if you have a better approach I would be happy to learn from it.

Comment: Using Constructor Injection (like how you injected `ICrudFactory` into `AuthenticationService`) is better since it cannot be changed once it is set. Did you try to make only `ZNodeDataContextFactory` the default registration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue, by creating particular containers for each generic repository.

```
public interface IZNodeContextFactory : ICrudFactory
{

}

public interface IMincronContextFactory : ICrudFactory
{

}
```

By doing it in this manner, I was able to simply do:

```
container.RegisterType<IZNodeContextFactory, ZNodeContextFactory>();
container.RegisterType<IMincronContextFactory, MincronContextFactory>();
```

This allowed the automatic dependency resolver to work, and implement since they now had unique names.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to inject `ZNodeDataContextFactory` into `AuthenticationService` ? A bit of the point with the injection is that the service should not now anything about the implementation. But if you really want a specific implementation you can create a named instance.

```
public class AuthenticationService
{
     private readonly ICrudFactory _factory;
     public AuthenticationService([Dependency("ZNodeData")] ICrudFactory factory)
     {
         _factory = factory;
     }
}
```

And in your configuration:

```
container.RegisterType<ICrudFactory, ZNodeDataContextFactory>("ZNodeData");
container.RegisterType<ICrudFactory, MincronDataContextFactory>("MincronData");
```

Alternatively:

```
    public class AuthenticationService
    {
         private readonly IEnumerable<ICrudFactory> _factories;
         public AuthenticationService(ICrudFactory[] factories)
         {
             // Now you got both...
             _factories = factories;
             var zNodeFactory = _factories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Factory == ZNode);
         }
    }


    public interface ICrudFactory
    {
         ICrud Create();
         // Something to identify the type of data. Maybe an enum?
         FactoryType Factory {get;}
    }

public ZNodeDataContextFactory : ICrudFactory
{
     ICrud ICrudFactory.Create()
     {
           return ZNodeDataContext();
     }

     FactoryType ICrudFactory.Factory
     {
        {get {return FactoryType.ZNode;}
     }
}
```